# How to reduce Modsecurity disk IO

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

Modsecurity generates a lot of disk io operations, and the file `www-data-ip.pag` is read and written continuously.
Is there any solution that can effectively reduce this? Could it be moved to RAM in some way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-%28v2.x%29#secdatadir directive, pointing to a previously created directory in ram:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/modsecurity
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/modsecurity
```

And

```
SecDataDir /mnt/ramdisk/modsecurity
```

(check permissions in that directory, that apache user can create files, etc)
And remember to doing it permanent in /etc/fstab:

```
tmpfs       /mnt/ramdisk/modsecurity tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noexec,nodiratime,size=1024M
```

The weird part is the "note" in the `SecDataDir` directive:

> Note : SecDataDir is not currently supported. Collections are kept in memory (in_memory-per_process) for now.

Additional information (how to read the file, and some additional concurrency problems) can be seen in https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/2240.